# .NET to J2ME

Tags: .net, java-me, snmp

I have a .NET class that implements the SNMP protocol and I've been asked to port it to J2ME. Would I just create Java class and redist as a compiled .class file for the J2ME developers to use or is it more in depth than that?

Answer (score 1):

There is more to it than that.

You may want to download Netbeans, as it has nice support for J2ME, and should make it easier to go through the process.

You can look at the sidebar on this page, it shows the different steps to create the application.
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/02/09/j2me1.html

Answer (score 0):

That isn't easy.  There are networking samples for BlackBerry on the RIM site which use a lot of J2ME.  They may be able to point you in the right direction.  I've also got some old J2ME networking code I may be able to send your way if you can be more specific about what you need.